# Why does Typescript think my enum is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, redux

I'm using Typescript, Redux, and React, all of which are new to me so this probably has a simple fix I'm just not seeing.

I have an actions.ts file which includes an enum like this:

```
export enum AnimalTypes {
    CAT = 'CAT',
    DOG = 'DOG'
}
```

I import it in my reducers.ts file and was trying to use it in a log statement like this:

```
import {AnimalTypes} from './actions';

export function someFunction() {
    // Print the word "CAT"
    console.log(AnimalTypes[AnimalTypes.CAT]);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to launch my site:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAT' of undefined
  at someFunction (reducer.ts:5)
  at combineReducers.js:20
  etc.
```

My IDE doesn't give me any errors and neither does TSLint. I've read a bunch online trying to find the answer but the closest I came was from someone who didn't have the "export" keyword on their enum and I do.

What could be going on here?  I'd be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

EDIT: 
It's not the reverse mapping that it's having a problem with, rather any usage of the enum. That was just the shortest usage I could think of.  I'm actually using it in a switch statement:

```
import {AnimalTypes} from './actions';

export function otherFunction(animal) {
    switch (animal.type) {
        case AnimalTypes.CAT:
            // Do stuff
}
```

When I build the above code, I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAT' of undefined`

Comment: Is `someFunction` being called from `actions.ts` (perhaps indirectly) *before* the definition of `AnimalTypes` executes?

Comment: That's possible. How do I determine/control what order these things occur in?

Comment: Debugger, console.log, inspect the call stack, etc

Comment: should it not just be console.log(AnimalTypes.CAT); anyway, why is it being accessed like an array?

Comment: To go with @RyanCavanaugh's recommendation for looking at the call stack — 

I was getting a weird error with enums somehow not being defined, and a completely unexpected mention of a promise: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`

At the bottom of the call stack, there were all the enum imports for the specific file, and the one enum that was causing the trouble was, indeed, `undefined`. 

After tons of trial and error, moving those imports up to the top of the file made everything work.

Comment: @spjpgrd THANK YOU!!! That was my issue. I am using a custom lib, and I was importing enums from the library. I was also importing and injecting a service that imported the same enum. The problem: I imported the service before the enum at the top of the component.ts file..

Answer (score 2):

This feature of typescript is called "reverse mapping", and per the documentation it is only supported with numeric enums. Here is the snippet from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html:

> In addition to creating an object with property names for members,
>   numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to
>   enum names.

Comment: Added a clarification above with a better example.  It's not the reverse mapping that's causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your exact case: I imported an enum in my reducer and created that exact function which logged the enum, and it worked.

However, I just ran into the same problem in a slightly different context: I added the import for my AppRoutes enum in my SideNav file. Inside the SideNav file, in a `const popularArticles` that mapped through some JSON and returned some TSX, when I tried to `<NavLink to={AppRoutes.something}>` I got "cannot read property something of undefined" even though hovering over AppRoutes.something in the IDE would show me the correct value from the correct source. I think this is a pretty similar case to yours so I hope my solution will help future readers running into this problem.

What solved it for me was to integrate the `const popularArticles` (which was outside the SideNav class) into a variable `public popularArticles` inside the class, just before the constructor. I don't know why but upon further experimentation I found that apparently you can't access the enum outside of a class or SFC...

Answer (score 1):

What I did was this:

```
import {AnimalTypes} from './actions';

export function someFunction() {
    var animalTypesEnum = AnimalTypes;
    // Print the word "CAT"
    console.log(animalTypesEnum[animalTypesEnum.CAT]);
}
```

and it worked. TS v3.6.4